# Vue CLI 3 Prepending eval Function to Custom Template Tags

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I'm running a webpack-dev server to develop a Vue application (Vue CLI 3). Our company uses a custom templating language similar to ASP.NET (functions begin with <% prefix and close with %> suffix, and they're evaluated server-side), and this seems to cause a problem with the webpack-dev server. In the example below, I'm attempting to set the `specs` variable to `<%json_item_specifications%>`:

```
  export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      specs: <%json_item_specifications%>,
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, webpack will escape the json function with an eval function and return this as part of the export:

```
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__ ...
```

The leading eval causes the page to break, and I'm not sure exactly what part of the webpack stack causes this. I'm using the packaged webpack that comes with vue-cli 3, and I know that uses Babel under the hood.

I believe that Babel from webpack is parsing the <% as some other language and prepending the eval, but I can't find the parser configuration options online. Has anyone had issues with vue-cli parsing code in this way?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas about your issue:

1. You should try using X-templates (instead of Single File Components)
   or inline-templates with standalone version of Vue. you can read
   more about this here:
   https://sebastiandedeyne.com/dealing-with-templates-in-vue-20
2. Another possible solution is the localization of the specifications. I have experience only with Wordpress(PHP) but there you can create a Javascript object via PHP for settings which you can read later inside the template.